# How to pair up consecutive elements in a list, without overlap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Simple problem: I have `u = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. I want `v = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]`. How?

Obviously, one solution is:

```
v = []
for i in range(len(u)):
    j = 2*i
    v += [(u(j), u(j+1))]
```

But this is so ugly and lame I hate looking at it every time I do it. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) is a pythonic solution.

```
list(zip(u[::2], u[1::2]))
```

Comment: I forgot you could do `[::2]` in Python!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more general solution for iterables that don't support slice notation

```
def n_clusters(iterable, n=2):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)
```

Note that any leftover values (say your input list has an odd number of elements) aren't included in the output.  We an correct this by using the [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) function.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def n_clusters(iterable, n=2, fillvalue=None):
    return zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Both of the above will return iterators over the grouped values.  You can either build a list out of them manually

```
grouped_values = list(n_cluster([1, 2, 3, 4]))
# [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

or iterate over them directly

```
for a, b in n_cluster([1, 2, 3, 4]):
    ...
```

Comment: Should have been the accepted answer!